# Create TXT record for subsubdomain in Google Domains

Tags: domains, google-domains

I'm trying to set up a vanity URL and the support page instructs me to create a TXT record on a sub-subdomain:

[image: Instructions to create TXT subsubdomain]

In Google Domains, it's not clear how to do this.  Under "DNS" -> "Custom resource records", you can select TXT, but the "name" field does not allow periods, so I can't put `fdkey.support` there.

[image: Google Domains TXT record]

Comment: That's rough. Every DNS provider I've used allows periods in the "name" field, and that's the way you typically input a sub-subdomain like that, so Google Domains must be unique in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Silly me.  They do accept periods in the "name" input.  You just can't have a period at the end of the string, so if you paste in the name, it'll work.

Comment: "if you paste in the name, it'll work" - are you saying that you still can't _type_ the period when it occurs mid-name?

Comment: You have to type the name and then go back and add the period, it doesn't allow you to type the period when there's nothing after it.  Bad UX.